# SQL Server: case/if else -select and apply function only if present in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, if-statement, case

I have the following dynamic query that creates a pivoted table for each `account_id` against the products using an UDF. I need to add spaces after the UDF is executed depending up the `account_id` being matched to the specific tables. This works perfectly fine, and returns the 2nd table in the image, I just want to add some condition where it checks for account id's present in other tables and then adds spaces to output from the UDF eg- the account id in the pivot matches the id present in test_rev then 2 spaces if the account_id in the pivot matches the id present in test_oncontract then 3 spaces so on

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.A_NAME) 
            FROM TEST_11 c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT account_id, ' + @cols + ' INTO TEST_DETAIL from 
            (
                select account_id
                    , dbo.make_table(apple,ball,cat,dog) AS newvalue
                    ,a_name
                from test_sample
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX(newvalue)
                for a_name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

Image below shows how `make_table` udf converts the 1st table into 2nd just picking up the initials from each column name from the 1st table

[image]

I was able to call my function and add the required spaces withing the select.
But the case statement just executes the first condition and I cant get the records from the other tables. How can I implement if conditions instead of the case statements to to get data depending on all four conditions. Below is the code I am currently using:

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.a_name) 
            FROM CRS_PRODLINE c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT account_id, ' + @cols + ' INTO TEST_DETAIL  from 
            (select   account_id,
                    (case
                    when exists (select  account_id from [dbo].[TEST_R6]) 
                    then 
                    dbo.make_sam_indicator112(apple,ball,cat,dog)  + space(1) + ''rr''

```
                when exists (select account_id from tbl_noR6) 
                then 
                dbo.make_sam_indicator112(apple,ball,cat,dog) + space(2) + ''cc''

                when exists (select account_id from tbl_acct) 
                then 
                dbo.make_sam_indicator112(apple,ball,cat,dog) + space(3) + ''pp''

                when exists (select account_id from test_NA) 
                then 
                dbo.make_sam_indicator112(apple,ball,cat,dog) + space(4) + ''no''

            end) as newvalue,
            a_name
            from CRS_PRODLINE
       ) x
        pivot 
        (
            MAX(newvalue)
            for a_name in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '
```

execute(@query)

Comment: First of all, you should never have multiple data in a single table 'cell'. Down the line you'll regret doing that. Second, what's the point of attributes `PROD1` - `PROD5` if they have the same data? Finally, what will you do when you start selling `Carrots`?

Comment: Well I need to pick this data up on my front end reports, and this is just sample data closely related to the actual data!

Comment: to me it looks like you're doing it at the wrong layer: imo this should be done at the presentation layer (eg: ssrs, crystal & such).

Comment: @Paolo I added a solution to what I am trying to get,but all conditions inside my select are not being matched as the case statement falls off when the 1st condition is met. I need some IF logic to get data from all 4 tables